# NodeJS Canvas errors when setting up

Tags: node.js

I'd like to install Node Canvas but it doesn't work...

My errors : http://glui.me/?i=5dav7litin1nvz7/2014-01-28_at_21.01_2x.png/

Anthony

**EDIT #1**

Permissions : http://glui.me/?i=8sgj2apcr3hd9qw/2014-01-29_at_12.49_2x.png/

**EDIT #2**

User : http://glui.me/?i=m3ikml8udr4lr4b/2014-01-31_at_10.05_2x.png/

Root : http://glui.me/?i=g2o7gqpan7wuchj/2014-01-31_at_10.07_2x.png/

Comment: Did you follow the instructions [posted here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX)?

Comment: it seems that nodejs was installed with a different user in your server, check the folder permission of the nodejs using the `ls -l` command

Comment: Yes I follow the instructions but I got the same errors... Edit on post for permissions...

Comment: well check if the root user has permission for the node js, I can't see it because you hided the names.

Comment: See the root permissions on edited post...